# apparmor logging level - skip audit log

Tags: apparmor

How do I minimize apparmor logging?

Libreoffice is generating a large number of apparmor audit log statements. I want to know about access denials but don't want to see all these approvals in my journal output.

The logging persists even with :

```
systemctl status apparmor

apparmor.service - Load AppArmor profiles
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apparmor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2019-04-26 07:50:29 PDT; 4min 42s ago

....
```

Comment: Re. "I want to know about access denials but don't want to see all these approvals in my **journal output**", what is the command your using to generate the output?

Comment: @DKBose usually `journalctl -r` or `journalctl -f`. Is there a way to filter out?That would be great.  I have looked (quickly) through the man page and see only ways to filter in. grep seems not quite right for this.

Comment: I've not used journalctl and so can't help. `man journalctl` mentions a grep option, like `journalctl -r --grep=denied` but trying that gives me, on Kubuntu 18.04, `Compiled without pattern matching support`. Could you explain why you're looking at journalctl? I guess something like kern.log, for example, would be more amenable to `grep whatever` or `grep -v whatever`.

Comment: @DKBose I am interested in following system events and my understanding is that journalctl gives an aggregation of logs that I would otherwise have to access individually.  I see entries from ufw.log, kern.log, and so on. Once I recognize a pattern of predictable, verbose, and uninteresting entries I want to be able to set them onto ignore. Journalctl may not be the best tool for this interest. Why do you *not* use it?